# mongoDB is adding 4 hours and 5 hours to date field while inserting date format(YYYY-MM-DD) through datastage ? is this the normal behavior?

Tags: mongodb, timestamp, utc

case#1 -- when inserted the date format (2015-08-01 ) , in mongodb it shows as 2015-08-01T04:00:00.000Z, where i expected it to be 2015-08-01T00:00:00.000Z

case#2 -- when inserted the date format (2016-01-01 ) , in mongodb it shows as 2016-01-01T05:00:00.000Z
where i expected it to be 2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z

source data type used data stage : Date
target data type specified in mongoDB : Date

Question here is why  04:00:00 timestamp is coming even though source has only YYYY-MM-DD(with out time stamp) ?

can some one help to clarify this ?  is this usual behavior of mongodb ? is there any thing i can do to have only timestamp as T00.00.00.000Z at target.

requirement is to not convert the date into string format ..

Comment: Please read that doc 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/

Comment: Can you share the data and code you are using to insert the date into a document. Also, the target document format (sample).